# SOAP data returns from Postman but not with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Whenever I use Postman to make a soap post request, I get back the desired data. Using Guzzle, no data is returned. Im new to SOAP and using the resources online to go along.

I have omitted the variables for ease of read.

```php
$xml = (
  '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:app="<ACTION-URL>"> 
          <soapenv:Body>
            <app:' . $functionName . '>
              <request>'
                . $requestBody .
                '<authentication>
                  <username>'. $authObject->username .'</username>
                  <password>'. $authObject->password .'</password>
                  <user_id>'. $authObject->userId .'</user_id>
                  <dealer_id>'. $authObject->clientBranchId .'</dealer_id>
                </authentication>
              </request>
            </app:' . $functionName . '>
          </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>'
);

private function makeSOAPRequest($xml)
    {
      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

      $options = [
          'headers' => [
              'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
          ],
          'body' => $xml,
          'Authenticate' => [env('USERNAME'), env('PASSWORD')]
      ];
      $url = env('ROSETTA_API');

      $promise =  $client->requestAsync('POST', $url, $options);

      $response = $promise->wait();
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);

      if ($xml) {
          $json = json_encode($xml);
          return json_decode($json, true);
      }

      return false;
    }
```

Calling `makeSOAPRequest(..)`, I get back `false`. Using the same xml data in Postman, data is returned. Is there anything I've missed in the request header?

## Edit to use cURL

```php
      // Copied from Postman:

      $curl = curl_init();

      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://<URL>",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "Cookie: PHPSESSID=6419f1d96025a4a2c4d454de33fc6820"
        ),
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);

      curl_close($curl);

      return $response; // xml data in string format.
```

cUrl does work but not Guzzle. How to return as json? When I use `simplexml_load_string`, it's empty.

Comment: What happens if you enable the debug flag? Is the request being sent by guzzle, identical to postman?  Is guzzle receiving a response?

Comment: Hi. When debug is set to true, I saw a bunch of stuffs related to the host server and its ssl info. Nothing out of the ordinary and I saw: "upload completely sent off: 648 out of 648 bytes". Is there something specific to look for? I'll try using only cURL then rely later. Thanks

Comment: When done right there 's no need to transform xml to a php data structure. The transformation from xml to php is done by the soap client. Guzzle wouldn 't be my first choice, when dealing with soap requests and responses. The native PHP client does a better job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below parameters in your curl:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1
CURLOPT_POST => true

// IF NEEDED
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY

// IF NEEDED
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $soapUser.":".$soapPassword)
```

For Checking Error After `curl_exec` and before `curl_close`

```
if( curl_errno($ch) ){
    print_r(curl_error($curl));
}
```

In add these headers in your header if needed:

```
"accept" => "*/*",

// IF NEEDED
"accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate"
```

Add your request code in try catch block:

```
try{
   //request code
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getCode());
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```